# Can an iOS app interfere with the ipad keyboard?

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard

I ve been getting some reviews on my app about a freeze on the right side of iPad keyboard. I did not even know that could be possible?

Does anyone experienced anything similar?

Any help on this keyboard freeze problem would be really appreciated cause I m little bit lost.

Answer (score 1):

The "right side" of the keyboard is probably a [red herring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring).

There are only two ways you could interfere with keyboard input:

1. Your input field is rejecting certain characters, but not giving user feedback that you're rejecting them.
2. You are doing some long-running work on the main thread (like downloading data, reading to/writing from disk, etc.) If this is the case, move it to a background thread.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the answer! Point 2 is quite difficult, because reviews are talking about "right side". If your app gets frozen by blocking main thread, the whole app (and the whole keyboard) would be frozen I guess... About point 1, I m going to check it.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not readily possible from what I know, due to the strict permissions of the iPad and apple in general it would not be possible for an app to do this without you intentionally "hacking" the iPad. The only thing i could suggest is that the users are downloading malware to the iPad unwittingly through the site that you have made your app available ??